# ngrx/store, rxjs, unserializable state error

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am not sure why I am getting this in my angualr app:

```
Error: Detected unserializable state at "stateStore.currentSource"
```

The StateStore object looks like this:

```
export interface StateStore {
  currentDirectLog: any;
  currentCousinLog: any;
  currentSource: Source;
  currentCitation: Citation;
  currentForm: EntryForm;
  currentTemplate: Template;
}
```

and the object in question:

```
export class Source implements IRecord {
  id: string = void 0;
  title: string = void 0;
  type: string;
  refNbr?: string;
  listing?: string;
  classification?: string;
  description?: string;
  files?: string[];
  template?: any;
  tags?: string[];
  lastUpdate?: number;
  refOnly?: boolean;
  z?: any;

  constructor () {
    this.type = 'Source';
    this.refNbr = '';
    this.listing = '';
    this.classification = '';
    this.description = '';
    this.tags = [];
    this.z = {};
  }
}
```

I have tried removing the constructor and swapping out the "void 0" initializations with an empty string. No change.

Comment: Have you checked the value of other properties within `stateStore.currentSource`? I'm guessing values of properties of type `any` may cause problems. You didn't mention the version of @ngrx/store you are using but @ngrx/store 8 appears to be picky when serializing objects (see [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1951) and [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1993)). Alternatively, you could change [`strictStateSerializability`](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictstateserializability) to false, if that's an option you can do with your app.

Comment: I don't think `class` can be serialized during `redux store` initialization process. Why can't you use `interface` instead of `class`?